# Linux Symbolic Link Append Name

Tags: linux, find, wildcard, symlink

Can someone help create a symbolic link where I append my own string to the name of the link? Here's the code that I have so far:

```
find /home/folder1/*.txt -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
find /home/folder2/*.txt -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
```

So that command works to create my symbolic link but I would like to append my own text to the link name because I could have the same file name in each folder and in the destination I need to find a way to give unique name to the symbolic link. So I was thinking of creating the sym links to look like this:

```
folder1_doc1.txt
folder2_doc1.txt
folder1_doc2.txt
folder2_doc2.txt
```

I'm thinking the script would look something like this:

```
find /home/folder1/*.txt -type f -exec ln -s {} "folder1_" +\;
find /home/folder1/*.txt -type f -exec ln -s {} "folder2_" + \;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues here.

1. The name of the matched file is in `{}`.
2. The name in `{}` is the complete path to the file (in your case `/home/folder1/a.txt`). You need to strip everything until the last `/` to have the file name. One solution is to use [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and work from there why we need to use `##` for largest removal and `*/` for the glob to be matched:

   ```
   $ a="home/files/folder1/s"; echo $a ${a##*/}
   home/files/folder1/s s
   ```
3. You cannot use `{}` inside a `${...}` construct. Thus, I'll replace your `find ... -exec ...` command with one using a `for` and doing the same thing:

   ```
   for file in `/home/folder1/*.txt`; do ln -s $file folder1_${file##*/}; done
   ```

PS: There's also `basename` which can be used instead of `${a##*/}` but it still cannot be used in `-exec` part of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream editors like awk to do quickly things like this.  Try e.g.:

```
find /home/folder1/*.txt -type f | awk -F '.txt' '{printf "ln -s %s %s_CUSTOM_TEXT.txt\n", $0, $1}'
```

That will print out a bunch of commands that might be close to what you would want to type in the terminal.  Play around with the awk strink to get it to say exactly what you want and then pipe the results to sh:

```
find /home/folder1/*.txt -type f | awk -F '.txt' '{printf "ln -s %s %s_CUSTOM_TEXT.txt\n", $0, $1}' | sh
```

Be careful when doing this kind of thing; make sure you dont pipe a bunch of commands to sh that you don't actually want being executed!

Comment: You need to decide exactly what you want for custom text before a complete solution can be given.  The problem with what you suggested is that if subfolders of e.g. folder1 have files of the same name then they'll both get the same name for the symbolic links. E.g.: /home/folder1/subfolder1/t.txt and /home/folder1/subfolder2/t.txt would both get links named folder1_t.txt . A simple solution would be to e.g. number all of the text files, from the first to the last find result.